# copy-item with wmi : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have a problem to copy an item from a unknown drive letter to the user folder.

Here is the code :

```
Copy-Item -Path .((gwmi win32_volume -f 'label=''FlashDrive''').Name+'flex\\update\\log.txt') -Destination $ENV:UserProfile\test.txt;
```

Error Output:

```
Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If there really is a device with the label "FlashDrive" following should work:

```
Copy-Item -Path ((gwmi win32_volume -f 'label=''FlashDrive''').Name + "flex\update\log.txt') -Destination $ENV:UserProfile\test.txt
```

I removed the `.` after `-Path` and the path now uses `\` instead of `\\`.

I tested it on my USB and it worked.